# Kendo chunk upload not split the uploaded file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, chunking

I am newbie in using `kendoUpload` control (**Kendo UI v2014.3.1316**), with `chunk` upload option. I have a web application, and using `kendoupload` control for upload files, it's need chunk upload feature because, there is a chance to upload larger file. Please see my code below.

**Html**

```
<input name="upload" id="mediaflUpload" type="file" />
```

**.js**

```
 $("#mediaflUpload").kendoUpload({
    async: {

        chunkSize: 5000000, // Will separate the file into chunks of size 5000000 bytes.
        concurrent: true, // Will upload all files simultaneously.
        autoRetryAfter: 300, // Will attempt a failed chunk upload after 300ms.
        maxAutoRetries: 4, // Will attempt the same failed chunk upload 4 times.
        saveUrl: "/File/ChunkSave",
        removeUrl: "/File/Remove",
        autoUpload: true
    },
    multiple: false,
    success: OnSuccessMediaFileUpload,
    upload: OnUploadMediaFileUpload,
    error: OnErrorMediaFileUpload
});

function OnUploadMediaFileUpload(e) {
debugger;
//var data = result.response;

var chunkMetaData = {
    UploadUid: "mediaflUpload",
    FileName: '',
    ContentType: '',
    ChunkIndex: 1,
    TotalChunks: 1,
    TotalFileSize: 30000000
};

e.data = {
    metaData: JSON.stringify(chunkMetaData)
};
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult ChunkSave(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string metaData)
    {
        if (metaData == null) { 
            return Save(files);
        }

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(metaData));
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ChunkMetaData));
        ChunkMetaData somemetaData = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as ChunkMetaData;
        string path = String.Empty;
        // The Name of the Upload component is "files"
        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                //path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), somemetaData.FileName);

                //AppendToFile(path, file.InputStream);
            }
        }

        FileResult fileBlob = new FileResult();
        fileBlob.uploaded = somemetaData.TotalChunks - 1<= somemetaData.ChunkIndex;
        fileBlob.fileUid = somemetaData.UploadUid;

        return Json(fileBlob);
    }
```

But I have a confusion about, kendo chunk has not split the file as per the `chunkSize` variable. If I upload a 30 MB file it's not split the 5 MB chunks. Is there any additional coding needed for this? I am not a expert in `chunk` upload configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading seems like the best approach - the feature was implemented in 2017 while you are using 2014 year version.

Answer (score 0):

In my question i think it's version problem. I am using **Kendo UI v2014.3.1316** version

Please see the below screenshots.

[image]

And i also checked the release history page.

[image]

Please advice if anyone have suggestions.

**Edit**

I update the Kendo UI version (**2018.3.1017**) and implement Kendo MVC Chunk Upload and now it works fine. Please see the following link to https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/chunkupload reference.